# How to load up a CSS file in a Wordpress child theme that's nested in a different folder and name?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

This is probably easy but I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.  Basically I've been making a bunch of Wordpress sites using child themes and usually the style.css is in the root folder of the theme and I've been using this in my functions.php file

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

While this file exists in the parent theme I'm using, it's blank and I realized the CSS file being used was a different file name and nested in

`\THEME-NAME\framework\css\site\stacks\THEME-CSS.css` as opposed to just 
`THEME-NAME\style.css`

So for the child theme do I have to recreate that folder structure and place a same named THEME-CSS.css in the same folder or do I just call it style.css and put it in the child themes root folder like it normally would be?  Any other advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add a stylesheet when in a child theme, these are the two options/behaviors:

```
// This will point to style.css in child theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_child_styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );

// This will point to style.css in the parent theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_parent_styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
```

As you said, when using [get_template_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) the path will always point to the parent theme folder. Use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) to point to the current / child theme folder, if applicable.